# Using Devise, how do I customize a failed authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a controller that uses Devise to authenticate actions. I'd like the default behavior of responding with a 401 on every action except for one. I'd like to proceed with the request but provide a different response body.

What method do I provide or override to accomplish this?

Comment: You can [generate controllers for devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers) and can edit the response section as per your requirement. You can also override particular method for a single controller instead of generating all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to skip the standard authentication on the page you want to do this on..

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:mydifferentcontroller]
```

then you will need add some logic for the controller to bring you to your alternate response

```
def mydifferentcontroller
  unless user_signed_in?
    ## add redirect_to if you want to send them to an entirely different page or whatever change in logic can go in here 
  end
end
```

Or if you just want to change a certain part of the page you can use the user_signed_in? in the view as well

```
- if user_signed_in?
  .classyclass You're signed in
- else
  .classyclass You're not signed in
```

if that's what you meant....